# Using text in a UITextField for a fetchRequest predicate

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I'm trying to use a value from a `UITextField` by passing it to a function which takes it as an argument and uses it as a `NSPredicate`. However, I'm getting zero results returned even though I've verified that the record I want is in the Core Data store.

The value is coming from this UITextField:

`@IBOutlet weak var liftName: UITextField!`

and I'm calling the function to retrieve the record like so:

`let lift = fetchLift(liftName.description)`

and here's the function:

```
  func fetchLift(liftNameFilter: String? = nil) -> Lift {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Lift")
    if let liftNameFilter = liftNameFilter {
      let filterPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "liftName = [c] %@", liftNameFilter)
      fetchRequest.predicate = filterPredicate
    }

    do {
      if let results = try coreDataStack.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [Lift] {
        lift = results
      }
    } catch {
      fatalError("There was an error fetching the lifts")
    }
    return lift![0]
  }
```

I've tried things like:

- commenting out the predicate:

  // let filterPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "liftName = [c] %@", liftNameFilter)
  // fetchRequest.predicate = filterPredicate
  }

and I get all 11 records in that entity returned so now I know it has to do with the predicate.

I also hard coded one of the values to search for like so:

```
let filterPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "liftName = [c] %@", "Bench Press")
```

and retrieved the record I need.

I did some caveman debugging and determined that this is what's being passed to the function:

```
<UITextField: 0x7ffb8340f0e0; frame = (86.5 148; 272.5 30); text = 'Bench Press'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7ffb81cf03e0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ffb8340e320>>
```

so I'd expect that `text` value to be plucked right out of there and used as the predicate but it's not.

I feel like this is one of those obvious things that I'm blind to now that I've stared at it so long. Hoping someone can help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Does your expected result match the incoming string **exactly**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `text` property of the `UITextField` to get the inputed value rather than using `description`.

```
let lift = fetchLift(liftName.text)
```

And just change your predicate to below:

```
let filterPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY liftName CONTAINS[c] %@", liftNameFilter)
```

Comment: Sigh. Thank you Santosh. That was my silly mistake. But why use `format: "ANY liftName CONTAINS[c] %@"` instead of what I had which was `format: "liftName = [c] %@"`?

Comment: That is for case-sensitive search. If just `= [c]` works for you then no prob, use it :)